# 99 bottles of beer on the wall in Ruby

Tags: ruby, loops

I am trying to write a Ruby loop for the song "99 Bottles of Beer On The Wall" for an exercise from the book "Learn To Programs". What am I doing wrong?  I have the following:

```
    def bottles_of_beer 

      i = 99

      while i < 99 and i > 0 

        puts "#{a} bottles of beer on the wall. #{a} bottle of beer."

      i = i - 1

        puts "Take one down, pass it around. #{i} bottle of beer on the wall."

      end

    end
```

Comment: How do you know something’s wrong?

Comment: I don't know, what *are* you doing wrong? What is your actual question? Are you getting an error of some kind, or undesired output, or what?

Comment: start loop with `i <= 99`

Comment: It's helpful to post exactly _what_ seems to be going wrong (incorrect output? fails to run at all?), as well as any error messages that might come up.

Comment: @JoshLee, nothing comes out. I tried that and it didn't work. This is what I have now: def bottles_of_beer 


 i <= 99

 while i <=99 and i >0 

    
    puts "#{i} bottles of beer on the wall. #{i} bottle of beer."

    i = i - 1

    puts "Take one down, pass it around. #{i} bottle of beer on the wall."

  end

end

Comment: You set `i` to a value, then immediately check if it is less than that?

Answer (score 3):

You are referencing undefined variable `a` in your first string.

Comment: thank you.....I fixed that!  I can be careless at little details like that.  Still it's something different.

Answer (score 2):

I have simplified your code by quite a bit:

```
i = 99
while i < 99 and (anything else)
  (anything)
end
```

Try and see if you can figure it out now.

Comment: sorry I had to wipe all the comments. I see both opinions on this, but ultimately I agree that for *this question*, this is actually a worthwhile shot at an answer. or close enough.

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

You have many problems with your code, not least of which *i* starts out equal to 99, so the rest of the code block is never evaluated. Even if you fix that, *a* will always be nil because you never assign anything to it.

### Fix Your Conditional

There are many ways to do this, but you probably want to use the [>=](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-3E-3D) or [<=](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-3C-3D) methods for your comparisons.

### Be More Idiomatic

Using [Integer#downto](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Integer.html#method-i-downto) and a block would be much more idiomatic. For example:

```
12.downto(1) { |count| p "#{count} bottles of beer on the wall..." }
p "You drank the whole case!"
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps...

```
99.downto(1) do |i|
  puts "#{i} bottle#{i==1 ? '' : 's'} of beer on the wall, #{i} bottle#{i==1 ? '' : 's'} of beer!"
  puts "Take one down, pass it around, #{i-1} bottle#{i-1==1 ? '' : 's'} of beer on the wall!"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To give you a definitive answer, there are three reasons why your code produces no output

- You set `i` to 99 and then loop `while i < 99 and i > 0`, so the loop is never executed. Since you are always *decrementing* `i`, there is no need for anything more than `while i > 0`
- You interpolate the variable `a` into the string you are printing. Since you haven't declared it your program will refuse to run, saying `undefined local variable or method 'a'`
- You never actually *call* your method.

Fixing these three problems gives this (non-idiomatic, but working) program

```
def bottles_of_beer
  i = 99
  while i > 0
    puts "#{i} bottles of beer on the wall. #{i} bottle of beer."
    i = i - 1
    puts "Take one down, pass it around. #{i} bottle of beer on the wall."
  end
end

bottles_of_beer
```

Comment: @CodeGnome: Thanks. I guess I fixed only one `a`